# Differentiating between gem module and AR model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using the Etsy gem, which as a `Listing` module.
I also have a corresponding `Listing` model in my app.

I'm trying to set up a sidekiq worker to work with the gem, call upon some methods and update the corresponding `Listing` row, but because I have `include Etsy` so that I can use the gem, rails gets confused and thinks I'm referring to the module instead of the model.

Here's the code:

```
class ListingWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Etsy

  def perform(seller, shop)
    access_token = {access_token: seller.oauth_token,
              access_secret: seller.request_secret}
    myself = Etsy.myself(access_token[:access_token], access_token[:access_secret])
    limit = 100
    offset = 0
    total_results = myself.shop.active_listings_count
until offset > total_results
  listings = Etsy::Request.get("/shops/#{shop.shop_id}/listings/active",
                               access_token.merge(limit: limit.to_s,
                                            offset: offset.to_s,
                                            include_private: 'true',
                                            includes: 'Images:1:0'))
                          .to_hash
  offset += limit

  listings['results'].each do |l|
    listing = Listing.find_by(listing_id: l['listing_id'])
```

end
end

Here's the error I get:

```
undefined method `find_by' for Etsy::Listing:Class
```

How do I differentiate between the module and the model and make rails understand I mean a db table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to `include Esty`? I just skimmed the gem's README; that module appears to be used as a namespace, not as something to be `include`d into the class. In addition, all of your code (above) would work perfectly well without the module inclusion.

Comment: For example, you don't need to `include Esty` in order to call methods on the module, like `Etsy.myself`.

Comment: To answer your question directly, you can use `::Listing` instead of `Listing`, to indicate that the "top level" `Listing` class should be used. However, as I said, I think the module inclusion is unnecessary in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much Tom, I'm very new to rails and didn't realize I didn't need to include it in order to use it :) Works perfectly! If you'd like to write it as an answer instead of a reply, I'd be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your problem is simply not to `include Esty`:

```
class ListingWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(seller, shop)
    # ...
  end
end
```

The purpose of `include` is to add methods defined with the module into your class.

For example, if I defined a module:

```
module Tom
  def hello
    puts "Hello!"
  end
end
```

And you wanted to call `hello` directly within your `ListingWorker` class, **then** you'd need to `include Tom`.

On the other hand, suppose I just define a "namespaced" method within a module, such as:

```
module Maayan
  def self.example
    puts "Example"
  end
end
```

Then, this should be invoked by referencing the module - i.e. `Maayan.example`.

You can do this from anywhere (provided the file containing this code is loaded); you don't need to `include` anything.

And that's what you're doing here -- in order to run code such as `Etsy.myself` or `Etsy::Request.get`, you don't need to `include` the module. You're calling methods on the module directly, not mixing the module's methods into your own class.

---

However, if you *did* find yourself in such a situation, where you have a nested class which conflicts with the top-level definition, note that ruby lets you explicitly access the globally scoped class by prepending `::` to the class name.

In other words, you can use `::Listing` to explicitly reference your own class.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate all your help! :)